# Accessing structs in a vector of lists

Tags: c++, list, vector, struct

I have a vector of lists of structs named Edge

so,

```
vector<list<Edge>> adjA;
```

and my struct looks like:

```
struct Edge {
   int weight;
   ... 
}
```

Assuming my adjA is already filled with Edges, how would I accessing those edges' variables?

```
vector<int>weights;
for(uint i = 0; i < adjA.size(); i++) //iterating through vector
{  for(uint j = 0; j < adjA[i].size(); j++) //iterating through list
   {
      weights.push_back(adjA[i][j].weight); //compiler error
   } 
}
```

error:

```
no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::list<Edge> > >::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::list<Edge>}’ and ‘uint {aka unsigned int}’)
       weights.push_back(adjA[i][j].weight);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `std::list` doesn't have an `operator [] ()`.

Comment: maybe you need a vector of vector if you need direct access

Comment: be wary of std::list. it is virtually never a superior choice to vector, even if the operations for which vector incurs a O(n) penalty are not uncommon.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo

The linked video has the founder of C++ supporting this rationale.

Answer (score 3):

`std::list` doesn't have an `operator [] ()`

You can use range-based `for` loops:

```
for (const auto &edges : adjA)
{
    for (const auto &edge : edges)
    {
        weights.push_back(edge.weight);
    }
}
```

Or iterators:

```
for (auto it = adjA.begin(); it != adjA.end(); it++)
{
    for (auto jt = it->begin(); jt != it->end(); jt++)
    {
        weights.push_back(jt->weight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not access elements of stl list with [] operator, however you can use iterators to iterate list:

```
vector<int>weights;
for(uint i = 0; i < adjA.size(); i++) //iterating through vector
{  
    for (std::list<Edge>::iterator it = adjA[i].begin(); it != adjA[i].end(); ++it)
    {
        weights.push_back(it->weight);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah ha, thank you. Yeah just realized I can't access lists like an array. Have to use the iterator

Comment: You got to the answer first. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this somewhat dated reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/), `list` doesn't have a `[]` operator. Instead, try using an `iterator`:

```
for(std::list<Edge>::iterator it = adjA[i].begin(); it != adjA[i].end(); ++it)
{
    weights.push_back(it->weight);
}
```